# Difficulty decoding image with base64 library

Tags: python, tkinter, base64

I'm having trouble decoding an image when I import it from another file.
I have four .py files to make two buttons.
In the first, on line 21, the button works and brings the image, in the second, on line 28, which is imported from another file, it appears as a button but without an image. How can I resolve this?

lab.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import base64
from imagens import *
from cores import *
from widgets import *


class Janela(Images):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.images_base64()
        self.tamJanela()

    def tamJanela(self):
        self.janela_doMenu = tk.Tk()
        janela = self.janela_doMenu
        # janela.state('zoomed')
        janela.title('Disk Gás Gonçalves')
        janela.configure(background=preto_claro)
        janela.geometry("%dx%d" % (janela.winfo_screenwidth(), janela.winfo_screenheight()))

        # Here the code works ###############################################################
        self.img_icoName = tk.PhotoImage(data=base64.b64decode(self.editUser))
        self.rotulo_nome2 = tk.Button(master=janela, image=self.img_icoName, activebackground='#00FA9A', bg='#4F4F4F',
        highlightbackground='#4F4F4F', highlightcolor='#4F4F4F')
        self.rotulo_nome2.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        # Here the code does not work #######################################################
        # I'm importing from widgets.py #####################################################
        Botoes(janela)

        janela.minsize(1200, 640)

        janela.mainloop()

Janela()
```

widgets.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import base64
from imagens import *
from cores import *


class Botoes(Images):

    def __init__(self, local) -> None:
        self.images_base64()
        self.local = local
        self.bt()
        
    def bt(self):
        self.img_icoName = tk.PhotoImage(data=base64.b64decode(self.editUser))
        self.rotulo_nome2 = tk.Button(master=self.local, image=self.img_icoName, activebackground='#00FA9A', bg='#4F4F4F',
        highlightbackground='#4F4F4F', highlightcolor='#4F4F4F')
        self.rotulo_nome2.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

cores.py

```
preto_claro = '#4F4F4F'
verde_médio = '#00FA9A'
vermelho_salmão = '#FA8072'
azul_seleção = '#F0FFFF'
verde_limão = '#00FF00'
branco_gelo = '#EDEBE6'
```

imagens.py

```
import base64


class Images:

    def images_base64(self):
        self.addUser = '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'
        self.editUser = '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'
```

I tried to create a button by importing the base64 image from another file.
There are two buttons in the application, one works and the image appears, the other does not work and the image does not appear. I would like to make the second one work.

All the code will generate this image. The bottom button that doesn't show the image is in the widgets.py file
I don't know why, but when I import it, it doesn't work.

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLGIH.png)]

Thank you in advance for your attention and I apologize if something was wrong or out of standard, my English is not very good.

Comment: You need to use an instance variable to store the reference of `Boteos()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because there is no variable referencing the instance of `Botoes()`, so it will be garbage collected (so as the image inside it).

Just use a variable to store the instance of `Botoes()`:

```py
class Janela(Images):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.images_base64()
        self.tamJanela()

    def tamJanela(self):
        self.janela_doMenu = tk.Tk()
        janela = self.janela_doMenu
        # janela.state('zoomed')
        janela.title('Disk Gás Gonçalves')
        janela.configure(background=preto_claro)
        janela.geometry("%dx%d" % (janela.winfo_screenwidth(), janela.winfo_screenheight()))

        # Here the code works ###############################################################
        self.img_icoName = tk.PhotoImage(data=base64.b64decode(self.editUser))
        self.rotulo_nome2 = tk.Button(master=janela, image=self.img_icoName, activebackground='#00FA9A', bg='#4F4F4F',
        highlightbackground='#4F4F4F', highlightcolor='#4F4F4F')
        self.rotulo_nome2.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # need a variable to store the instance of Botoes
        # to avoid garbage collection
        botoes = Botoes(janela)

        janela.minsize(1200, 640)

        janela.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]